# How to pause before parsing in jsoup?

Tags: java, parsing, jsoup

I need to pause my script before parsing (i want to wait for some information), but how can i do this in Jsoup?

I tried this:

```
link = Jsoup.connect("link").wait(100).get();
```

But this doesn't work for me.

Comment: Define "doesn't work". What is the expected behavior and what is the actual behavior?

Comment: Jsoup is not browser emulator so it doesn't have JavaScript engine. If you need to let JS load more elements before parsing then jsoup cant help you here. Take a look at web drivers like Selenium, or other libraries which include JS support.

Comment: If you want to wait some information, I think you should setting at your javascript e.g. setTimeout(callback, time);

Answer (score 1):

Usually the need for waiting arises when content is loaded via AJAX. Jsoup can't deal with such stuff, because it is not a browser. Jsoup simply interprets HTML. The connection stuff is more or less only a wrapper around Java connections.

I guess you need to either identify the AJAX calls directly and get the contents of the AJAX calls, or you can use a real browser, i.e. selenium with phantomjs or similar.